# Elements with type parameters in typescript TSX

Tags: typescript

is there a way to specify type parameters in TypeScript TSX syntax?
For example I have a class `Table<T>`, can i do something like

```
<Table<Person>
  data={...}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to specify type parameters in TypeScript TSX syntax

No.